# Parameters Error MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm getting a Parameters error here: `db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError` saying *"too few parameters, expected 1"*. I'm not sure exactly why. I'm referencing both tables. I'm also not 100% this is written correctly `Workername = " & DLookup("username", "attendance", GetNextAssignee("program", "Language", "username"))` I want `[Workername]` field to update to the workername that is linked to the `GetNextAssignee("program", "Language", "username")` which I'm not getting and it could be connected to the this error.

```
Public Function AssignNullProjects() As Long

    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT CFRRRID, [program], [language] FROM CFRRR WHERE assignedto Is Null"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        While Not rs.EOF

            strSQL = "UPDATE CFRRR,attendance SET assignedto = " & GetNextAssignee("program", "Language", "username") & ", assignedby = " & Forms!Supervisor!NavigationSubform!assignedby.Value & ", Dateassigned = #" & Now & "#, actiondate = #" & Now & "#, Workername = " & _
                              DLookup("username", "attendance", GetNextAssignee("program", "Language", "username")) & ", WorkerID = " & DLookup("UserID", "attendance", GetNextAssignee("program", "Language", "username")) & " WHERE CFRRRID = " & rs!CFRRRID
            Debug.Print strSQL
            db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If

    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Here is what the `Debug.Print strSQL` shows:

```
UPDATE CFRRR,attendance
SET
    assignedto = 7,
    assignedby = 33,
    Dateassigned = #5/16/2015 11:16:31 AM#,
    actiondate = #5/16/2015 11:16:31 AM#,
    Workername = Lillian,
    WorkerID = 6
WHERE CFRRRID = 6
```

Comment: Please copy the output from `Debug.Print strSQL` when you get that error, and paste it into your answer.  You should also paste it into SQL View of a new Access query and run it.  What word does Access interpret to  be the parameter?

Comment: I updated my question. I also put it in an SQL view of a query and it's not really giving me an error, just changing it slightly: 

`UPDATE CFRRR, attendance SET CFRRR.assignedto = GetNextAssignee("program","Language","username"), CFRRR.assignedby = Forms!Supervisor!NavigationSubform!assignedby.Value, CFRRR.Dateassigned = # Now #, CFRRR.actiondate = # Now #, CFRRR.Workername = DLookUp("username","attendance",GetNextAssignee("program","Language","username")), CFRRR.WorkerID = DLookUp("UserID","attendance",GetNextAssignee("program","Language","username"))
WHERE (((CFRRR.[CFRRRID])=[CFRRRID]));`

Comment: Also, if you notice in the `Debug.Print strSQL` `assignedto = 7` and `WorkerID = 6` but `WorkerID` should be 7 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems *Workername* is a text field and you want to store the string *Lillian* there.  Add quotes so the db engine will understand *Lillian* is literal text instead of the name of a parameter.

```sql
UPDATE CFRRR
SET
    assignedto = 7,
    assignedby = 33,
    Dateassigned = Now(),
    actiondate = Now(),
    Workername = 'Lillian',
    WorkerID = 6
WHERE CFRRRID = 6
```

Since the db engine supports the `Now()` function, you can ask it to store the value of `Now()` in your *Dateassigned* and *actiondate* fields.  That is simpler than taking the value of `Now()` in VBA and then adding `#` characters around that value to concatenate into the statement text.

I'm skeptical that `UPDATE CFRRR,attendance` was the right choice.  That would be a `CROSS JOIN` between the two tables and Access may therefore decide the query is not updateable.  I suggest you `UPDATE` just the *CFRRR* table.

Comment: I do want to just update `CFRRR` but I needed to put `attendance` there as well because of the `DLookup`. I may be wrong but I thought if I referring to a field in a table I had to have that table referenced in the beginning of the SQL.

Comment: In `DLookup()`, you tell it to look in the *attendance* table.  So that table name does not need to be included elsewhere in the query.

Comment: Makes sense, I removed that. Also how would I put `Lillian` in quotes? `Workername = " & _
                              DLookup("username", "attendance", GetNextAssignee("program", "Language", "username")) & "` Where would I put them here? I've tried it several ways and am getting an expression error.

Comment: `Workername = '" & _ DLookup("username", "attendance", GetNextAssignee("program", "Language", "username")) & "', WorkerID = "`

Comment: There is a whole lotta concatenating going on to build that `UPDATE` string.  You could avoid that by switching to a parameter query.  You also wouldn't need to both with delimiters for text or Date/Time values.  Are you familiar with parameter queries?

Comment: Great that worked. Now the error changed to Data type mismatch in the criteria expression. I'll ask another question. It seems that it may be connected to the coding here: `DLookup("username", "attendance", GetNextAssignee("program", "Language", "username")) & "`.Thank you for fixing the parameter error :)

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with parameter queries at all. I didn't even though that was a thing lol. I'm going to email you asking questions about that so that this doesn't get too long.